# Setting custom session id causes script / apache to hang

Tags: php, apache, session, curl, sessionid

I'm in the process of building a single sign-on system and I am using `cURL` to send a request off to a file on the main site and return the results / their user data; however, if the user logs into the secondary site via a cookie (ie; they aren't currently logged into the main site) I need to make sure they get logged into the main site at the same time and set some session variables so that they don't continuously have to keep logging in via a cookie on the secondary site.

Obviously we normally would end up with a different `session id` on the file I am calling via `cURL` and hence setting any `$_SESSION` variables there wouldn't be available to the secondary site; so I tried passing the `session_id` from the secondary site with the call via `cURL` and then in that file I did this to set the session id so that any `$_SESSION` variables I set there would then be available to the secondary site.

```
// Get session ID
$sid = trim($_GET['session_id']);

// Set the session id so we can get the added session data below via the forum
session_id($sid);

session_start();
```

However when I do that and try and access the secondary site the page won't load, it just hangs - I tried removing that code and loading it again but it won't load until I restart Apache.

Btw.. if it matters, this is on my local dev machine, which is Windows XP Pro.

Any ideas!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m assuming here that both your main and your secondary site are on the same server and use the same session settings, especially the same `session.save_path`, is that correct?
If so, that’s where your problem lies:

The default session handling mechanism of PHP works using files to save the session data.

And to avoid concurrent write access to the session file, the file gets *locked* as long as one script (one script *instance* would be more exact) is still working with the session. Every other script that wants to access that particular session has to “wait”, until the first one is finished using the session.

So with you trying on your secondary site to start your session with the session id already in use on your main site, the script on your secondary site can’t access the session because of that locking.
And since your main site’s cURL request is waiting for the secondary script to finish, which is itself still waiting for access to the session … you’ve got yourself a nice deadlock here :-)

---

What you can do, is call `session_write_close` in your main site script *before* making your cURL request – at that point all data is written to the session file, and the file lock is released.

You have to be aware though, that you can not use the session again in your main site script instance after that – well, you can still read data from and push data into the `$_SESSION` array, but since the session is already closed, all data that you alter in that array after that point will not be persisted any more. So do what you have to do with the session in your main script, then close the session – and then make your cURL request.

---

**Edit:** Well, come to think about it – not sure if the above actually helps here … because your whole *approach* might be flawed already. Calling a script via cURL on your secondary site will not actually set a session cookie for your secondary domain *in the user’s browser* – because every response of that secondary site’s script does not “land” in the browser, it lands in your main site script, because that’s where you doing the request from.

I think what you really need here, is to call a script from your secondary site *in the user’s browser* (JavaScript/AJAX request, iframe, embedded image), so that it’ll set a cookie with the session name and session id as value *under your secondary site’s domain* – only that will make PHP able to “recognize” the user’s browser once they navigate to your secondary site. Actually *opening* the session will not be necessary (still assuming that both sites use the *same* session), because the session is already started, and all it needs for PHP to pick it up on the secondary site is a matching session id from the cookie.

So try doing that instead – but be aware of the problems you *might* run into with that, since the browser will consider the cookie for the secondary domain as a *third party cookie* when you are trying to set it in the context of your main site (and the domains don’t match, e.g. one is not running on a subdomain of the other or something like that).

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response. I actually ended up passing the extra data needed via the same response and setting the session variables within the script on the secondary site; much simpler process haha..... but I appreciate your response and it most definitely will come in handy in the future if I ever run into something like this again.